# Iterating Through a Directory's Contents Through Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hdfs, sh

I have the following script that is supposed to iterate through the contents of an HDFS directory

```
#!/bin/bash

PATHS=$(java MyJava)
DELIM='|'
HDFSPATH=${PATHS}${DELIM}

while [[ ${HDFSPATH} ]]; do
  PATHARR=( "${HDFSPATH%%"DELIM"*}" );
  HDFSPATH=${HDFSPATH#*"$DELIM"};
done

SOURCEPATH=${PATHARR[0]}

for FILENAME in `hdfs dfs -ls ${SOURCEPATH} | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .txt$ | tr '\n' ' '`; do
  echo ${FILENAME};
done
```

And I run it as follows

```
sh myscript.sh
```

The .java file is

```
public class MyJava {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("/a/b/c/" + "|" + "/d/e/f");
  }
}
```

What I expect is this

```
/a/b/c/file1.txt
/a/b/c/file2.txt
```

But what I get is

```
/a/b/c/file1.txt /a/b/c/file2.txt
```

The newline character gets replaced by a space and the loop runs only once. But when I run the for loop directly through the shell, I get the expected result. Could someone help me with this?

The script runs in a Linux machine.

Comment: Just tested your script, works perfectly for me, have you ran in interactive mode to see what's happening when the script is progressing? like: `sh -x myscript.sh /a/b/c/`

Comment: @User123 I edited the question. $SOURCEPATH comes from a java program.

Comment: `awk '{print $NF}' | grep .txt$ | tr '\n' ' '` can be more simply written `awk '/.txt$/{print $NF}' ORS=' '`